# render the html contents of a controller's action inside a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to render the contents of an action (e.g new_sub_batch) inside a div.

I tried

```
<div id="newBatch">
<%= render :template => 'new_sub_batch.html.erb' %> 
</div>
```

but nothing is displayed.

I even tried  `<%= render :action => 'new_sub_batch' %>`..still nothing.

Any suggestion??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try file render:

```
<div id="newBatch">
<%= render :file => 'directory/new_sub_batch.html.erb' %> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want are partials. Distil the common markup that both views will use into a single file, and prefix its name with an underscore. Then call `render :partial => 'filename'`, where `filename` is the name of the partial without the underscore.

In your case, the code you pull out of `new_sub_batch.html.erb` might go in a `_batch.html.erb` partial, in the same directory as your other `sub_batch` views. You would render this partial with:

```
render :partial => 'batch'
```

In Rails3, you can simply use `render 'batch'`.

If you want to pass a variable to the partial, you can do so via `:locals`. Assuming you have a `@sub_batch` variable you want to pass, your call would look something like this:

```
render :partial => 'batch', :locals => { :sub_batch => @sub_batch }
```

While this doesn't strictly answer your question, I believe within the `ruby-on-rails` tag it's more important to explain the *Rails Way*, rather than help you do it the wrong way.